# Yii2 merge arrays

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I need merge arrays for json API. I have 3 requests:

```
$data['winners'] = Winners::find()->limit(8)->all();

$user = User::findIdentity($value->user_id);

$product = Products::find()->localized($lang)->where(['coupon' => $value->coupon])->one();
```

I need foreach all $data['winners'], get User with id from $data['winners'], and get Product from $data['winners']. After i need merge in 1 json all my data.

I try like this:

```
$data['winners'] = Winners::find()->limit(8)->all();
        foreach ($data['winners'] as $value){
            $user = User::findIdentity($value->user_id);
            $product = Products::find()->localized($lang)->where(['coupon' => $value->coupon])->one();
            $result = ArrayHelper::merge($product, $user);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an even more elegant solution in PHP:

```php
    $winners = Winners::find()->limit(8)->all();
    foreach ($winners as $value){
        $user = User::findIdentity($value->user_id);
        $product = Products::find()->localized($lang)
            ->where(['coupon' => $value->coupon])->one();
        $data[] = [
            'image'=> $product->prize_image,
            'user' => $user->firstname.' '.$user->lastname,
            'title' => $product->win_title,
        ];
    }
    return $data;
```

The [PHP array operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) `[]` in `$data[]` adds an array element at the end of the `$data` array.

Answer (score 0):

If  i understand correctly you question  you need  an array with all the $data[winners] istances and foreach instance merge the related  Produce and User
then you could use

```
 $result[] = array_merge($value, $product, $user);
```

.

```
    $data['winners'] = Winners::find()->limit(8)->all();
    foreach ($data['winners'] as $value){
        $user = User::findIdentity($value->user_id);
        $product = Products::find()->localized($lang)->where(['coupon' => $value->coupon])->one();
        $result[] = array_merge($value, $product, $user);
    }
```

Comment: I get error Setting unknown property: common\models\Winners::buy_image, because there is no such thing in the model Winners

Comment: @Elexer  The code you mention is not in you question and not my answer  ..  so seems related  to another question  ..

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
$winners = Winners::find()->limit(8)->all();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($winners as $value){
            $user = User::findIdentity($value->user_id);
            $product = Products::find()->localized($lang)->where(['coupon' => $value->coupon])->one();
            $data[$i]['image'] = $product->prize_image;
            $data[$i]['user'] = $user->firstname.' '.$user->lastname;
            $data[$i]['title'] = $product->win_title;
            $i++;
        }
        return $data;
```